# Use TAB to change selection and focus in a JSplitPane (from one JTable to another)

Tags: java, swing

I have a very simple GUI using 2 JTables in a SplitPane and I want to use TAB to remove selection in one JTable and move focus and select the first row of the other JTable. The gui is just each JTable in its own ScrollPane. Both ScrollPanes in the SplitPane and the SplitPane is in my class which extends JFrame.

The way I went about it was:

```
    table_LEFT.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("TAB"),
                        "doSomething");

    table_LEFT.getActionMap().put("doSomething",
                         new myAction(table_RIGHT));
```

This will register the key TAB to myAction which extends AbstractAction. In AbstractAction I have to override the 'actionPerformed(ActionEven ae)' method. The problem is I cannot access the other table (in this case the 'table_RIGHT' from the ae event. I have to go through the containers to the top where the property of myClass is the other table. This seems very cumbersome and wrong + plus I managed to select a row in table_RIGHT, but don't give it focus ... . Am I going about this right?

Comment: Yes, your solution is correct.

Answer (score 1):

> I have to override the 'actionPerformed(ActionEven ae)' method.

Correct.

> The problem is I cannot access the other table (in this case the 'table_RIGHT' from the ae event.

When you create your Action, you can always pass in the reference to the right table when you create the Action. Then you store the reference so you can access it in the actionPerformed(...) method.

> plus I managed to select a row in table_RIGHT, but don't give it focus ... .

If you have a reference there is no reason you can't give the focus to the table. The basic code would be:

```
rightTable.requestFocustInWindow();
rightTable.changeSelection(...)
```

If you need more help then post your [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Hi, can you be a more specific how to carry the right table reference to the actionPerformed method? It seems to me that the only argument this method takes is the ae ActionEvent?